# Change Class of element using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I have a menu structure like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>pageA</h3>
    <ul>
      <li id="a1"><a href="index.php?pageA&id=1">1</a>
      </li>
      <li id="a2"><a href="index.php?pageA&id=2">2</a>
      </li>
      <li id="a3"><a href="index.php?pageA&id=3">3</a>
      </li>
      <li id="a4"><a href="index.php?pageA&id=4">4</a>
      </li>
      <li id="a5"><a href="index.php?pageA&id=5">5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>pageB</h3>
    <ul>
      <li id="b1"><a href="index.php?pageB&id=1">1</a>
      </li>
      <li id="b2"><a href="index.php?pageB&id=2">2</a>
      </li>
      <li id="b3"><a href="index.php?pageB&id=3">3</a>
      </li>
      <li id="b4"><a href="index.php?pageB&id=4">4</a>
      </li>
      <li id="b5"><a href="index.php?pageB&id=5">5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I want to change`<li>` classes with javascript. I can change child `<li>` with following code. But i can't change class of parent `<li>`.

```js
document.getElementById("a1").className = 'active';
```

Comment: Can't you just give the outer `li` an ID?

Comment: Try document.getElementById("a1").parent.className = 'active';

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should work to replace the class of an element with that ID.

Check out this page:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp

**Example**
Overwriting an existing class name with a new one:

```
<div id="myDIV" class="mystyle">I am a DIV element</div>

document.getElementById("myDIV").className = "newClassName";
```

**Example**
To add a class to an element, without overwriting existing values, insert a space and the new class name:

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").className += " anotherClass";
```